# How to dynamically change the content of HTML in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am getting the path of HTML file from IFile-
The method is like -

```
public IStatus runCustomizer(final IFile file, final IDOMPosition position)
    {}
```

Through this IFile, I am getting an HTML file. Now I want to modify the html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the question is restricted with Eclipse. You can read file into any DOM presentation e.g. JDom, Saxon, Xerces etc. and perform XSLT transformation on it. This way is most common but heavy. You can perform customization on DOM presentation manually. These ways are acceptable only if your html file is well-formed. If no you can work with it like with text file but this is more error prone approach.